# Managing Android app development with Android Studio + IntelliJ

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea, project-management

I work on a project with a team for an android game for Parrot's drones using SDK3. We are sudent so new a bit new to team development on a project of that size.

We all have "modules" assigned. By modules, I mean some members work on the android UI, some work on OpenGL, some on the network...

I am looking for a coherent way to organize the project structure. It would be great if anyone could work on Android Studio. But as some don't need Android at this stage of the development, and, correct me if I am wrong, since I believe it is not possible to program standard Java in Android Studio, or at least run/test it, it is not a good idea for them to use it.

Some needs to use Android with external libraries, some also Android with external libraries, some Android without any libraries, some just plain Java with/without external librairies.

If I am wrong in my assumption, then great! We can all use the same android studio project, but then, how to organize the android studio project?

And If I am right, what do you think is the best way to manage the project and organize the project structure using those two IDE and all the features they offer (like modules)?

Thank you for in advance for your interest, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having "pure" Java and "Android Java" within the same project and even the same module is not a problem. The same is true for "normal" unit tests that run on the local JVM. You can see an example in the excellent [u2020 demo app](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020).

It might be desirable to have separate modules with separate dependencies (for example a "pure" Java plus the app itself) to improve reusability and sharing of code over multiple projects. But if you don't have multiple projects and don't want to share any JARs, why bother?

Regarding the organization of your source layout I recommend looking at various existing apps and to adapt the style that fits your needs:

- [Wire](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-android)
- [Ribot](https://github.com/ribot/ribot-app-android)
- [Pocket Hub](https://github.com/pockethub/PocketHub)
- [Telegram](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)
- [Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

Comment: Thanks!

Ok so we can all work in android studio! It sounds decent for an Android IDE supporting modules, I wasn't sure about how to use it... No I'll have to move all the mess in Android Studio! Thank you!

Comment: Mmh... I can't use packages inside modules in android studio?
I wanted to create modules to separate the part of the project so the teams can work on each modules separately, I thought they could add packages to divide they work but it seems that it is not possible... So I should I organize the project then?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I should right click on the java folder to be able to create a package! I have to learn the tools...